# Apache HTTP Infinite Messages -- The current context is NOT a context of GBA service

Tags: android, mysql, apache, sockets, infinite-loop

I am building a group chat application with backend server in XAMPP and websockets to send the messages. As for individual chat, one to one messaging, it works just fine but once I send a group chat message it displays this cryptic error in LogCat outlined with heading `The current context is NOT a context of GBA service`.

After the error appears, the group messages continually repeat in the users screen, with the BroadcastReceiver constantly accepting the same message, the first in the MySQL database, infinitely.

As other posts have outlined, they note to use HttpURLConnection to prevent this error, which I have (see the socketer class below).

Is there anything that can be changed about my server configuration that can prevent this error and the constant pulling/repeating of that same first message in the MySQL database?

The LogCAt Error:

```
07-30 20:26:23.206: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()
07-30 20:26:23.236: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()
07-30 20:26:23.236: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null
07-30 20:26:23.246: D/memalloc(16298): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5b3ad000 size:491520 offset:0 fd:68
07-30 20:26:23.256: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.
07-30 20:26:23.266: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(16298): (thUse=3539) isCurrentProcessRequestedGba()#finished   result=false
07-30 20:26:23.266: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(16298): (thUse=3539) isCurrentProcessAllowedToUseGba()#started   result=false
07-30 20:26:23.266: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    The GBA permission wasn't requested for this process.
07-30 20:26:23.266: D/memalloc(16298): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5b5bb000 size:245760 offset:0 fd:82
07-30 20:26:23.276: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
07-30 20:26:23.276: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(16298): (thUse=3539)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
07-30 20:26:23.286: D/memalloc(16298): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5b886000 size:491520 offset:0 fd:89
07-30 20:26:23.326: D/memalloc(16298): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5c5e3000 size:491520 offset:0 fd:93
07-30 20:26:23.456: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null
07-30 20:26:23.456: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.
07-30 20:26:23.476: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(16298): (thUse=3539) isCurrentProcessRequestedGba()#finished   result=false
07-30 20:26:23.506: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(16298): (thUse=3539) isCurrentProcessAllowedToUseGba()#started   result=false
07-30 20:26:23.516: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    The GBA permission wasn't requested for this process.
07-30 20:26:23.516: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
07-30 20:26:23.516: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(16298): (thUse=3539)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
07-30 20:26:24.167: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=false
07-30 20:26:24.177: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
07-30 20:26:24.187: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(16298): (thUse=3539)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
07-30 20:26:24.337: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=false
07-30 20:26:24.337: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
07-30 20:26:24.337: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(16298): (thUse=3539)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
07-30 20:26:24.557: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=false
07-30 20:26:24.557: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(16298): (thUse=3539) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
07-30 20:26:24.557: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=3539) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(16298): (thUse=3539)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handle
```

d.

Socketer Class:

```
public class Socketer implements SocketerInterface
{
    /
    Global ipAddress = new Global(); 
    private final String AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://" + ipAddress.getIpAddress() + "PRIVATE/"; // change to your WebAPI Address

    private int listeningPort = 0;

    private static final String HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED = null;

    private HashMap<InetAddress, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<InetAddress, Socket>();

    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    private boolean listening;

    private class ReceiveConnection extends Thread {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        public ReceiveConnection(Socket socket) 
        {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
            Socketer.this.sockets.put(socket.getInetAddress(), socket);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
             try {
    //          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;

                 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                 {
                     if (inputLine.equals("exit") == false)  // as long as have noted exited yet, will continuing reading in 
                     {
                         //appManager.messageReceived(inputLine);                        
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                         clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                         clientSocket.close();
                         Socketer.this.sockets.remove(clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                     }                       
                 }      

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ReceiveConnection.run: when receiving connection ","");
            }           
        }   
    }

    public Socketer(Manager appManager) {   
    }


    public String sendHttpRequest(String params)
    {       
        URL url;
        String result = new String();
        try 
        {
            url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            out.println(params);
            out.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result.concat(inputLine);              
            }
            in.close();         
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result = HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED;
        }

        // This is the output of the datastream from the server ie. <data> (bunch of data...etc) </data>
        return result;


    }

    public int startListening(int portNo) 
    {
        listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
            this.listeningPort = portNo;
        } catch (IOException e) {           

            //e.printStackTrace();
            this.listeningPort = 0;
            return 0;
        }

        while (listening) {
            try {
                new ReceiveConnection(serverSocket.accept()).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();              
                return 2;
            }
        }

        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            Log.e("Exception server socket", "Exception when closing server socket");
            return 3;
        }


        return 1;
    }


    public void stopListening() 
    {
        this.listening = false;
    }

    public void exit() 
    {           
        for (Iterator<Socket> iterator = sockets.values().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket) iterator.next();
            try {
                socket.shutdownInput();
                socket.shutdownOutput();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {               
            }       
        }

        sockets.clear();
        this.stopListening();
    }


    public int getListeningPort() {

        return this.listeningPort;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Are you using WiFi or regular cell network ?

Comment: @slott i fixed there error a while back. it ended up being the database was not being updated with the column `read = 1`, therefore the same message was being pulled in given it 'thinks' that message was never read.